# Create new column based on multiple conditions in multiple columns

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table, bigdata, grouping

UPDATED to include multiple options in new variables:

I'm working with a messy big data patient file (> 40 million rows). Each patient (`id`) has several rows. Each row (roughly) represents one consultation with a symptom/disease code (`icpc`). I add a new column with categories for patients with specific conditions (based on columns `icpc` and `icpc2`).

My raw data.frame (`df`) looks something like this (this is fabricated data, `id` is much longer in my dataset and I left out irrelevant columns which I like to drop):

```
    id icpc icpc2 reg.date 
1:  123 D95 F15   19JUN2015 
2:  123 F85       15AUG2016 
3:  332 A01       16MAR2010 
4:  332 A04       20JAN2018
5:  332 K20       20FEB2017
6:  100 B10       01JUN2017 
7:  100 A04       11JAN2008
8:  113 T08       18MAR2018
9:  113 P28       19JAN2017 
10: 113 D95 A01   16JAN2013
11: 113 A04       01MAY2009
12: 551 B12 A01   03APR2011
13: 551 D95       09MAY2015
```

Say I want to categorize patients with `D95` and/or `A01` as yes in the new column named 'condit' (based on two columns `icpc` and `icpc2`). The following works:

```
cond1 <- c("D95", "A01")
setDT(df)[, condit := ifelse(any(icpc %in% cond1 | icpc2 %in% cond1), "yes","no"), by=id]
df
```

But now I want to categorize several codes from `icpc` and `icpc2` in the new column `condit`. So for instance, D95 and/or A01 from `icpc` or `icpc2` as `A`, `A04` and/or `T08` as `B`, `B10` as `C` in `condit`. NOTE: `A` should overwrite `B` (see row 4, 8 and 11), `B` should overwrite `C` etc (as it is possible id may have fall in several categories).

This is the data.frame (`df`) I want:

```
    id icpc icpc2 reg.date  condit
1:  123 D95 F15   19JUN2015 A
2:  123 F85       15AUG2016 A
3:  332 A01       16MAR2010 A
4:  332 A04       20JAN2018 A
5:  332 K20       20FEB2017 A
6:  100 B10       01JUN2017 C
7:  100 A04       11JAN2008 C
8:  113 T08       18MAR2018 A
9:  113 P28       19JAN2017 A
10: 113 D95 A01   16JAN2013 A
11: 113 A04       01MAY2009 A
12: 551 B12 A01   03APR2011 A
13: 551 D90       09MAY2015 A
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Adding 'any' helps somewhat... 'if_else(any(icpc %in% c("D95", "A01"), 'yes', 'no'))' not with OR function

Comment: It's not the complete answer, it does not allow for R to find A01 or D95 in both columns (icpc and icpc2)

Comment: The responders have done it for you this time but please follow the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page when posting in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your large (> 40 million rows) data set, the **data.table** package might be a good choice:

```
library(data.table)

cond1 <- c("D95", "A01")
setDT(df)[, condit := ifelse(any(icpc %in% cond1 | icpc2 %in% cond1), "yes","no"), by=id]
df
```

---

```
     id icpc icpc2  reg.date condit
 1: 123  D95   F15 19JUN2015    yes
 2: 123  F85       15AUG2016    yes
 3: 332  A01       16MAR2010    yes
 4: 332  A04       20JAN2018    yes
 5: 332  K20       20FEB2017    yes
 6: 100  B10       01JUN2017     no
 7: 100  A04       11JAN2008     no
 8: 113  T08       18MAR2018    yes
 9: 113  P28       19JAN2017    yes
10: 113  D95   A01 16JAN2013    yes
11: 113  A04       01MAY2009    yes
12: 551  B12   A01 03APR2011    yes
13: 551  D95       09MAY2015    yes
```

---

**Data**:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(123L, 123L, 332L, 332L, 332L, 100L, 100L, 
113L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 551L, 551L), icpc = c("D95", "F85", "A01", 
"A04", "K20", "B10", "A04", "T08", "P28", "D95", "A04", "B12", 
"D95"), icpc2 = c("F15", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "A01", 
"", "A01", ""), reg.date = c("19JUN2015", "15AUG2016", "16MAR2010", 
"20JAN2018", "20FEB2017", "01JUN2017", "11JAN2008", "18MAR2018", 
"19JAN2017", "16JAN2013", "01MAY2009", "03APR2011", "09MAY2015"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

---

**Edit**: for multiple conditions:

```
cond1 <- c("D95", "A01") # A
cond2 <- c("A04", "T08") # B
cond3 <- "B10"           # C

setDT(df)[, condit := if(any(icpc %in% cond1 | icpc2 %in% cond1)) "A" else 
                         if(any(icpc %in% cond2 | icpc2 %in% cond2)) "B" else
                            if(any(icpc %in% cond3 | icpc2 %in% cond3)) "C" else "", by=id]

     id icpc icpc2  reg.date condit
 1: 123  D95   F15 19JUN2015      A
 2: 123  F85       15AUG2016      A
 3: 332  A01       16MAR2010      A
 4: 332  A04       20JAN2018      A
 5: 332  K20       20FEB2017      A
 6: 100  B10       01JUN2017      B
 7: 100  A04       11JAN2008      B
 8: 113  T08       18MAR2018      A
 9: 113  P28       19JAN2017      A
10: 113  D95   A01 16JAN2013      A
11: 113  A04       01MAY2009      A
12: 551  B12   B10 03APR2011      C
13: 551  D96       09MAY2015      C
```

---

**Data**: (slightly modified from the original since no "C" condition was found.

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(123L, 123L, 332L, 332L, 332L, 100L, 100L, 
113L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 551L, 551L), icpc = c("D95", "F85", "A01", 
"A04", "K20", "B10", "A04", "T08", "P28", "D95", "A04", "B12", 
"D96"), icpc2 = c("F15", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "A01", 
"", "B10", ""), reg.date = c("19JUN2015", "15AUG2016", "16MAR2010", 
"20JAN2018", "20FEB2017", "01JUN2017", "11JAN2008", "18MAR2018", 
"19JAN2017", "16JAN2013", "01MAY2009", "03APR2011", "09MAY2015"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

---

Tested on a data frame with 40M rows:
system.time(...)

```
#    user  system elapsed 
#  111.11    1.17  111.97
```

Using dplyr:

```
# Error: cannot allocate vector of size 274.7 Mb
# Timing stopped at: 4.19 1.11 5.39
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using data.table.
The output does not give yes for all id which have A01 or D95 in one of their rows. See the table in my question.

Comment: Please update your question to incorporate this new information. And be as clear as possible.

Comment: See edited answer. You'll have to consider situations where a person can be in more than one category. The sequence of the if statements will then be pivotal. If belonging to multiple categories is important, then you'll have to modify the code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should write:

```r
df.cat <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(condit = 
           if_else((icpc %in% c("D95", "A01")) | (icpc2 %in% c("D95", "A01")) ~ 'yes', 'no'))
```

You should not use `==` when more than one choice is possible. By the way, I added parentheses to your logical comparisons

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `any` as you have already discovered since you want to assign values to entire groups.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(condit = if(any(icpc %in% c("D95", "A01") | icpc2 %in% c("D95", "A01"))) 
                     "yes" else "no")
```

Or a faster option without `if`/`else` would be

```
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(condit = c("no", "yes")[(any(icpc %in% c("D95", "A01") | 
                                        icpc2 %in% c("D95", "A01"))) + 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if any element of `c(icpc, icpc2)` is in the desired codes. Note that result is a simple character string `yes` or `no` so we can just use `if` rather than `if_else`.

```
DF %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(condit = if (any(c(icpc, icpc2) %in% c("D95", "A01"))) "yes" else "no") %>%
  ungroup
```

A second approach is to convert the data to long form in which case there will only be one icpc column (called `value`), set `condit` and then convert back to wide form (or you might want to just leave it in long form).  The `select` at the end reorders the columns to be in the same order as the input, i.e. id column first, icpc column second, etc.

```
library(tidyr)
DF %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("icpc")) %>%
  filter(name != "") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(condit = if (any(value %in% c("D95", "A01"))) "yes" else "no") %>%
  pivot_wider %>%
  select(names(DF))
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "id icpc icpc2 reg.date 
123 D95 F15   19JUN2015 
123 F85       15AUG2016 
332 A01       16MAR2010 
332 A04       20JAN2018
332 K20       20FEB2017
100 B10       01JUN2017 
100 A04       11JAN2008
113 T08       18MAR2018
113 P28       19JAN2017 
113 D95 A01   16JAN2013
113 A04       01MAY2009
551 B12 A01   03APR2011
551 D95       09MAY2015"
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
L <- sub(" (\\S+) ", ",\\1,", L)
L <- sub(" +", ",", L)
DF <- read.csv(text = L, check.names = FALSE, as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```